# paskening in front of Rebbi who is your father inlaw

Tags: halacha, minhag, family-members, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

It is [assur](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591) to pasken (rule on a [halachic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597) matter) in front of one's [Rebbe](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/593) (Eiruvin 63).
If one's father-in-law is his Rebbe and his wife asks him (her husband) a halachic question in front of her father, can the son-in-law answer since his wife has to keep the customs of her husband?

Comment: In such a case why would it matter that the Rebbe is also the Father of his wife? If she has to follow davka what *he the husband* says why would it matter then who the Rebbe is?

Comment: why can't the father in law just answer according to the husband's opinion? and if he doesn't know it, then how is that considered paskining in front of someone else: they don't even know what you hold?

Comment: What they said. Or, what does keeping customs of one's husband have to do with this question?

Comment: Actually it would seem to me that the prohibition would be stronger by the father in law as one is also required to give him Kavod according to the halakhot of Kibud Av V'Em.  Further several of the Amoraim married the daughters of their Rabbanim, and that did not eliminate the prohibition for them.

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam, in the Mishna Torah, [Hilchos Talmud Torah 5:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910979/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm) states that if a student  is asked a direct question that requires an immediate answer to prevent a transgression, he can respond to the question.  To respond to questions anywhere, the student must first establish himself as a halachic authority and then he can respond to questions either (1) after his rebbe's death, or (2) with the permission of his rebbe.

When Rabbi Gedaliah Anemer, zt'l, was still alive, he often allowed his students who had moved on to rabbinic posts (teaching or pulpit) to speak from the bimah.  When practical questions of halacha were asked by the congregation, they would all defer to Rabbi Anemer who usually gave permission to his students to answer (unless the issue was really a hot topic).